# Dynamically create object from object array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I need to turn into a new single object.

This is structure of array:

```
class QueryFilter {
    filterName;
    filterValue;
}

let filter1 = new QueryFilter();
filter1.filterName = "SpamScore";
filter1.filterValue = 5;

let filter2 = new QueryFilter();
filter2.filterName = "Pages";
filter2.filterValue = 50;

let filters = [filter1, filter2];
```

I need to turn filters into an object like this:

```
let newObj = {
    SpamScore: 5,
    Pages: 50
};
```

I have been trying with map and assign but I cant figure out the way I am supposed to do this.  Does this require reflection of some type or is there a simple way?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: I tried using assign and map and it didn't work so I don't see point of posting it as I am not sure if it is even those methods that I should be using.

Comment: `for(let filter of filters) { newObj[filter.filterName] = filter.filterValue }`

Comment: isn;t that setting an array or it is same as object property?

Comment: It's the same as `object.property`

Comment: more fully: `let newObj = {}; for(let f of filters) { newObj[f.filterName] = f.filterValue }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
filters.reduce((r, i) => {
  r[i.filterName] = i.filterValue;
  return r;
}, {});
```

The idea is to loop over the `filters` object, and in each iteration, assign the key-value to the result.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `reduce` into an object would do it:

```js
class QueryFilter {
}

let filter1 = new QueryFilter();
filter1.filterName = "SpamScore";
filter1.filterValue = 5;

let filter2 = new QueryFilter();
filter2.filterName = "Pages";
filter2.filterValue = 50;

let filters = [filter1, filter2];

console.log(
  filters.reduce((a, { filterName, filterValue }) => (
    Object.assign(a, { [filterName]: filterValue })
  ), {})
);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks.  Funnily that method didn't come up when i was googling, thank you very much i will accept when timer allows

Answer (score 0):

```js
let newObj = {}
    
filters.forEach(x=> {
  newObj[x.filterName] = x.filterValue;
})

console.log(newObj)
```

Alternatively you can also use [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to achieve what you want